# make progressdialog while waiting to receive SMS

Tags: java, android, sms, progressdialog

I am new to Android and Java. The following code is to send and wait for receiving SMS. As the process may takes about 3 minutes, I need to have a progressDialog until SMS is received. Could you send me an applet to do this ?

```
package com.examples.TOLD;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Sms extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

static TextView smsReceive;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{       
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.sms);

    Intent i = getIntent();
    // Receiving the Data
    String reg = i.getStringExtra("reg");
    String port = i.getStringExtra("port");

    String smsMessage = 
        "REG=" + reg + 
        "PORT=" + port;

    // Show SMS sent message on screen 
    TextView smsSend = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.smsSend);
    smsSend.setText(smsMessage);
    Log.i("smsSend",String.valueOf(smsSend.getText()));
    // Send SMS message
    SmsManager sm = SmsManager.getDefault();
    String number = "5556";
    sm.sendTextMessage(number, null, smsMessage, null, null);

    // Receive SMS message
    smsReceive = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.smsReceive);

}
public static void updateMessageBox(String msg)
{
    smsReceive.append(msg);
}    
}
```

Here is another class to receive SMS:

```
package com.examples.TOLD;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.util.Log;


public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    Bundle bundle=intent.getExtras();

    Object[] messages=(Object[])bundle.get("pdus");
    SmsMessage[] sms = new SmsMessage[messages.length];

    for(int n=0;n<messages.length;n++){
        sms[n]=SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) messages[n]);
    }

    for(SmsMessage msg:sms){
        String num = msg.getOriginatingAddress();
        Log.i("SMS sender",num);
        if (num.equals("15555215556")) {
        Sms.updateMessageBox("\nFrom: " + msg.getOriginatingAddress() + 
                "\n" + "Message: " + msg.getMessageBody() + "\n");}           
    }
}
}
```

Comment: hey you create receiver to get SMS so why you need progress dialog?? Please read this---> http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html

Comment: The app is sending a SMS and wait for that number to reply a SMS. The process takes a while. So I need a progress dialog. Excuse I don't quite understand the link you sent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can try to reconsider your approach. You can't expect user will be waiting for up to 3 minutes for the SMS. So you code looks right (except the part of the static method cos I explain you later), but once your message is sent, I'd show a message that your app is waiting for the message, and when the message is received in the `SmsReceiver`, you can communicate with the `Sms` activity.

**But**, you shouldn't use that static method to update the content of the activity for several reasons (UI can't be updated in background or most important when the `SmsReceiver` is fired `SMS` activity can even non exist). The right way would be sending an intent from the receiver. You can see a detailed step by step example in the pdf contained in this [link](http://p2p.wrox.com/content/articles/creating-android-apps-send-and-receive-sms-messages-and-send-email) in the section  Receiving SMS messages.

Comment: May be I have missed that part, the example in the pdf seems does not contain how to add a progressdialog. Could you show this to me?

Comment: That example is not showing how to show a ProgressDialog. That could be done like this:

    ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    dialog.setMessage("message");
    dialog.show();

But your problem will be still the same, if you try to contact from the receiver to the activity through the static method your app will crash. Take a look at the example in the pdf to learn how to change your static method for sending an intent that could close the ProgressDialog

Answer (score 0):

I Don't think sending and receiving should be in the main thread.  You can use AsyncTask to receive the message in background. you can show the dialog before starting the task and
close it after recieving

Answer (score 0):

Lookup http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html for painless background threading.

Simply display your progress dialog in OnPreExecute and dismiss it when the task reaches OnPostExecute.

Comment: May I ask: the AsyncTask needs to use "extends". How could I do that in "SmsReceiver" as the class is "extends BroadcastReceiver"? This might be to easy to you. Sorry I am new to this.

Comment: It's okay, you just make an inner class that extends AsyncTask. For example : class LookThroughSMS extends AsyncTask, if you need to read messages in your inner class, make it a global variable or pass it into the constructor of the LookThroughSMS class.